# Input Widget Class that can take values above 99

Tags: pyqgis, qt-designer

I developed a plugin in which the user can add a length of a line and than the line gets created.

in QtDesigner I used a Spin Box. However, I just realized that a Spin Box takes only values to 99. 300 ist not possible.

Than I thought I could use a Line Edit instead but when running the tool I get the error message "'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'value'". Is there a Widget I can use so that the user can enter lenghts above 99?

Comment: Did you try `self.dlg.spinBox.setMaximum(300)`? *example object name.

Comment: And if you use QLineEdit the text is retrieved with `text()` method instead of `value()`.

Comment: I retrieve the QLineEdit with text() but afterwards I can parse them to a float or int. That helped me out, thank you.

Comment: Great- I have posted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default maximum for `QSpinBox` is 99, but you can change this with the `setMaximum()` method:

```
spin_box.setMaximum(300)
```

Otherwise, if you wish to use a `QLineEdit` instead, retrieve the value using the `text()` method. You can then cast it to an integer or a float if you wish:

```
val = int(line_edit.text())
```

or

```
val = float(line_edit.text())
```